# tense mismatch "pseudo-continuous" and future

Tags: grammar, tense, verbs

> He's just a kid. As he grows up, he will stop doing it.

I am wondering if this sentence is grammatical. "He will stop doing it" implies he will stop at one point, but "as he grows up" refer to a large lapse of time, so there's a mismatch. How would you fix this sentence?

Comment: There's no mismatch. At some point as he grows up, he'll stop doing it. Maybe he'll do it less and less until he reaches a point that he stops, but maybe not. Maybe there'll be nothing gradual about it and he'll just stop cold-turkey at some point. It doesn't really matter. All that's conveyed is that he'll stop doing it at some point as he grows up.

Comment: There's nothing to fix in this sentence. It's correct as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no mismatch. At some point as he grows up, he'll stop doing it. Maybe he'll do it less and less until he reaches a point that he stops, but maybe not. Maybe there'll be nothing gradual about it and he'll just stop cold-turkey at some point. It doesn't really matter. All that's conveyed is that he'll stop doing it at some point as he grows up

So there's nothing to fix in this sentence. It's correct as it stands.